# Keep HTML table variable width regardless of td content

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have an html table that grows narrower and wider as the browser window is dragged narrower and wider. Each row in this table initially contains columns of summary data, and each row has an icon that when clicked will open a new dynamic table row immediately beneath the summary row, and in which I want to display another table containing detail information.

My problem is that the detail table that appears in each dynamically added table row is very wide. In an attempt to keep the outer table from widening to accommodate the inner detail table, I added a div with a style of overflow-x: scroll; inside of the detail info's td tag; however, although it adds the horizontal scroll bar, the main table also widens to accommodate the inner detail table. I want the main table to retain it's width and layout regardless of what is put into the dynamically added rows.

I found that if I put table-layout: fixed; on the outer table tag, that table stops widening to accommodate the inner detail table when it appears, and the scroll works fine, but it has the drawback of making all of my main table's columns the same width.

Does anyone know of a better way to keep the outer table able to grow and shrink with the browser window, and yet stop it from widening when the wide inner content is shown?

Comment: This website is all about code, you need to make [mre] in order for someone to help you.

Comment: the "jquery" tag is wrong

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions.

1. `table-layout: fixed` doesn't essentially make all columns of the same width.
   You can use `<col>` tags to specify column widths. The problem is that you can't use auto-calculated column widths with this approarch.
2. Add `style='position: relative'` to problematic `<td>` of the outer table. Add `<div style='position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: auto'>` inside it as a container for the inner table. You can specifify the width of `<td>` with `width` attribute.